# Neo4j - No such ServerPlugin error

Tags: java, neo4j

Spinning my wheels here and hopefully someone can be a help.  And I'll preface this by saying I am new to Neo4j.  I have spent much time searching for this error online and do not see anything that pertains to what is being encountered.

I am trying to launch a call to a java class on my local version of Neo4j (using port 7474) via Google's Advanced Rest Client utility.  When the call is made the below error is thrown.

A jar file was created and placed in the plugins directory and everything looks like it is in place for this to run.  Here is the value being used to make the call from Advanced Rest Client  ->

```
"http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/InsertTestNode/graphdb/insertTest"

message: "No such ServerPlugin: "InsertTestNode""
exception: "PluginLookupException"
fullname: "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginLookupException"
stacktrace: [7]
0:  "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.extension(PluginManager.java:115)"
1:  "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:156)"
2:  "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.
     invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)"
3:  "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension
     (ExtensionService.java:134)"
4:  "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"
5:  "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.
    TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)"
6:  "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"
```

Any insight you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you followed the steps in [the documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-plugins.html)? I suspect you are probably missing something.

The documents state that `the .jar file must include the file META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin`. Are you sure this has been included in the Jar?

You also need to `make sure the directories listings are retained in the jarfile by either building with default Maven, or with jar -cvf myext.jar *, making sure to jar directories instead of specifying single files.`

If you do all of this and then place the jar in the plugins folder you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  The jar file did include the plugin file BUT the entries in the file were not in sync with my classes due to some refactoring I did.  Once that was cleaned up all worked well.  Chalk that up to a learning experience.